# Proper way to implement unsubscribe function

Tags: php, mysql, email, unsubscribe

I'm currently using PHPMailer to send out an email to a mailing list, however I am looking to create an unsubscribe function because I cannot in good conscience not give the option.

The only problem I'm facing is doing it in a safe manner. What I've had in mind so far was to add an href back to my website that would link to a page like http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?email=useremail@test.com but with this method anyone can delete any email they want, or delete the entire mailing list. I'm not sure how I can bypass this issue. My MySQL database only contains a unique email ID which is just their position in the database (the first email added has an ID of 1 and the second has an ID of 2 and so on) and column for the email address itself.

Comment: generate a unique one-time token (time elapsed based also), and using that token targeting the user's email in the query/column. There is plenty of solutions out there.

Comment: this Q&A for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142935/how-to-generate-unsubscribe-link-for-newsletter might even be a duplicate for this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387229/how-to-generate-link-for-unsubscribing-from-email and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240915/how-to-add-one-click-unsubscribe-functionality-to-email-newletters

Comment: Personally, I kind of like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17143081/ where you could ask the user upon clicking the link, their secret key which you really should add to your table.

Comment: Create another column in your table and generate a unique token for each email. Then you can attach this token to unsubscribe URL along with email.

Comment: For those who happen to stumble upon this question, an FYI: It's not just a matter of conscience - it's required by the FTC: https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this

http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?email=useremail@test.com&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
$_GET["token"] = hash_hmac('sha256', $email.$email_id, $site_salt);
```

if token valid then process subscribe.

P.S. I'm not sure why you got a downvote by my guess is because you didn't realize you were legally required to provide an unsubscribe.

Comment: This is really useful, thanks! I do have an unsubscribe function, but it's kind of clunky (it is just a mailto with the subject unsubscribe).